# How to print the b-th prime number coming after n?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to write a c++ program which gets an integer n (n>=1 && n<=100000) from the user and puts the sum of its digits into b. The output needed is the b-th prime number coming after n. I'm an absolute beginner in programming so I don't know what's wrong with the for loop or any other code that it doesn't show the correct output. For example the 3rd prime number after 12 (1+2=3) is 19 but the loop counts the prime numbers from 2 instead of 12, so it prints 7 as result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return false;
    for(int i = 2; i <= (n/2); i++)
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    long int n;
    int b = 0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n >= 1 && n <= 100000){
        b += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    for(int i = n, counter = b; counter <= 10; i++)
        if(isPrime(i)){
            counter++;
            if(i > n)
                cout<<counter<<"th prime number after n is : "<<i<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

So one of the possible solutions to my question, according to @Bob__ answer (and converting it to the code style I've used in the initial code) is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(long int number)
{
    if(number <= 1)
        return false;
    for(int i = 2; i <= (number / 2); i++)
        if(number % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int sumOfDigits(long int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(number >= 1 && number <= 100000)
    {
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

long int bthPrimeAfter(int counter, long int number)
{
    while(counter)
    {
        ++number;
        if(isPrime(number))
            --counter;
    }
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    long int number;
    cin>>number;
    int const counter = sumOfDigits(number);
    cout<<bthPrimeAfter(counter, number)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have destroyed the value in `n` to produce `b` in the `while` loop. When the `for` loop comes around, `n` keeps being zero.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had completely forgotten this rule of programming.

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia page on [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)s? Did you read the wikipedia page on [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)s ? Did you look into [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website? Did you read about [numerical digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit)s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [dratenik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14215102/dratenik) said in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143154/how-to-print-the-b-th-prime-number-coming-after-n#comment118681726_67143154):

> You have destroyed the value in `n` to produce `b` in the `while` loop. When the `for` loop comes around, `n` keeps being zero.

That's a key point to understand, sometimes we need to make a copy of a variable. One way to do that is passing it to a function by value. The function argument will be a local copy which can be changed without affecting the original one.

As an example, the `main` function could be written like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime(long int number);
//            ^^^^^^^^ So is `n` in the OP's `main`

int sum_of_digits(long int number);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is a local copy.

long int nth_prime_after(int counter, long int number);

int main()
{
    long int number;
    // The input validation (check if it's a number and if it's in the valid range,
    // deal with errors) is left to the reader as an exercise.
    std::cin >> number;

    int const counter = sum_of_digits(number);

    std::cout << nth_prime_after(counter, number) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The definition of `sum_of_digits` is straightforward.

```
int sum_of_digits(long int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while ( number )        // Stops when number is zero. The condition n <= 100000
    {                       // belongs to input validation, like n >= 0.
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;       // <- This changes only the local copy.
    }
    return sum;
}
```

About the last part (finding the nth prime after the chosen number), I'm not sure to understand what the asker is trying to do, but even if `n` had the correct value, `for(int i = n, counter = b; counter <= 10; i++)` would be just wrong. For starters, there's no reason for the condition `count <= 10` or at least none that I can think of.

I'd write something like this:

```
long int nth_prime_after(int counter, long int number)
{
    while ( counter )
    {
        ++number;
        if ( is_prime(number) )
        {
            --counter;  // The primes aren't printed here, not even the nth.
        }
    }
    return number;      // Just return it, the printing is another function's
}                       // responsabilty.
```

A lot more could be said about the `is_prime` function and the overall (lack of) efficiency of this algorithm, but IMHO, it's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: As did what you indicated, it's printing the correct output needed! I can't thank you enough. Your answer was such a great help for me! 
I'm trying to do various codes and practice of some given exercises, so don't really know what was the author's purpose for creating this algorithm. Simply I wanted to reach the correct output that was out of my actual knowledge of programming.